# Discord bot js dont respond on my commands

Tags: javascript

Its a index.js with simple handling why him dont respond my commands?

```
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = 
require('discord.js'); 
const prefix = require('./config.json');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

client.login(token);
//here a command(in directory commands) (new file) 
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        return interaction.reply('Pong!'); 
    },
};
```

can give  config. json
erorr havent only bot dont respond on my commands
and prefix is %
who know why bot dont respond on my messages?

Comment: What? Add what?

Comment: I suggest adding [discord.js] tag (actual name does not have brackets, this syntax used to express a tag name) to get more chance to be picked up